# row operation in same table and same coloumns

Tags: sql

i have a little problem to discuss i hope it will easy for you.
suppose i have table A with 2 columns as

```
item          price
milk           25
milk           50
milk           100
Butter         25
Butter         100
Butter         200
```

now i want to display a table B derived from table A as

```
item          price growth rate
milk           0
milk           100
milk           100
Butter        100
Butter         200
Butter         100
```

formula for growth rate for row1 is

```
((row[1]-row[0])/row[0])*100
eg for 1st row ((50-25)/25)*100
```

can you suggest a SQl Query for it

Comment: sql server/Mysql/Oracle?

Comment: Also, is there another column indicating the order?  Or from which order can be inferred?

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying the easy way to get some homework done.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick for you is to write SQL that will get two consecutive rows in a single row.

Depending on the server there are a few ways to do that

For example you could join each row from one query to subquery that will get the first row that has a value lower then the value in current row.

To get the results you want you will also need to use a function that will convert nulls to 0.

Note: Your example in results row 4 lists growth rate 100; this is inconsistent with the example in the first row.

Comment: thank! But I could not find proper t sql since if I am using inner join for same table first row is repeating for rows of second part.

Comment: You'll need to show more of your tables structure to have a ready made query; the way to join consecutive rows in SQL is to prune unwanted results (like the rows with same value of some unique key, and also to limit the results to the first of the rest of the records). As I said, if you want help with that better show the structure of your tables (list table names, primary keys, and the column that you use to establish the order, plus fix your example, it is ambiguous)